# GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate conforming to protocol Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im am trying to use some sample code from Google Maps SDK for IOS.  The code below gives me an error message: Type `ViewController` does not conform to protocol `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate`. See code below. Does anyone know what is not conforming.

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!,
        didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace!) {
            searchController?.active = false
            // Do something with the selected place.
            print("Place name: ", place.name)
            print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
            print("Place attributions: ", place.attributions)
    }

    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController!,
        didAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!){
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: ", error.description)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the sample code on the site is incorrect. The protocol method is actually called [didFailAutocompleteWithError](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/protocol_g_m_s_autocomplete_results_view_controller_delegate-p.html#a673456c0a26a76cf4f2452131fa59eab), not `didAutocompleteWithError`.